# Are edit notifications no longer working?

Tags: support, edits, notifications

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094320/can-i-obtain-tls-secrets-from-an-http-client-to-decrypt-my-own-https-conversatio) yesterday, and some seven hours later, a small edit was made to it by another user. However, I was not notified - there was no red notification bubble, and nothing was added to my inbox messages.

Is this a bug, or are edits from high-rep users not notified? The editor in this case has 40K of rep, I wonder if that is relevant?

To be clear, I am not complaining about the edit, just wondering if I have encountered a buglet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I think I have spotted why this happens. I've noticed on the main Meta site, there is [an answer to a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415). For trivial edits, the notification is suppressed, and since this was a tag-only edit, I imagine that would qualify as trivial. I didn't know that!